# jQuery - dynamic concatenation of strings resulting from two button sets

Tags: jquery, input, concatenation

I'm trying to get jQuery to concatenate two strings in an input field, where each string is the result of the user pressing one button each in two button lists.
The field value should update each time a different button is pressed, and thus show the latest combination of buttons used.

Here is how far I got:

http://jsfiddle.net/Argoron/YYNSm/

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/YYNSm/10/ is what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var buttonData = [null, null];
    $("#lang input:button").click(function() {
        buttonData[0] = $(this).val();
        if(buttonData[0] && buttonData[1]) {
            $("#camouflage").val(buttonData[0] + ', ' + buttonData[1]);
        }
    });

    $("#letters input:button").click(function() {
        buttonData[1] = $(this).val();
        if(buttonData[0] && buttonData[1]) {
            $("#camouflage").val(buttonData[0] + ', ' + buttonData[1]);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks very much,  
und schönen Tag noch !

Comment: Btw, storing the two values in properly-named variables instead of an array would be better. Additionally, moving the code to check if both values are set and update the displayed value into a separate functions would make sense (D-R-Y).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you mean, but this code makes the latest combination of language and letter: http://jsfiddle.net/JG6Aw/1/

```
var lang = '',
    letter = '',
    $cam = $('#camouflage');

$("#lang input").click(function() {
    lang = $(this).val();
    update();
});

$("#letters input").click(function() {
    letter = $(this).val();
    update();
});

var update = function(){
    $cam.val(lang + ',' + letter);
};
```

Comment: if user click first on letters then it failsss

Answer (score 0):

Use this jquery, I've done how far i understood your problem

```
var allowpress=false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#lang input[type=button]").click(function() {
        $("#camouflage").val($(this).val());
        allowpress=true;
    });

    $("#letters input[type=button]").click(function() {
        if(allowpress) {
        $("#camouflage").val( $("#camouflage").val() + ',' + $(this).val());
        allowpress=false;
        }
    });

});
```

you can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/gubhaju/wTFGm/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var languages = ['French', 'English', 'Spanish', 'German'];
    var letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];

    $("input[type=button]").click(function() {       
        var selections = [];
        var previous = $("#camouflage").val().length > 0 ? $("#camouflage").val().split(',') : [];

        var isLetter = $.inArray($(this).val(), letters)  > -1;

        selections = previous;

        if (previous.length == 1){
            selections[$.inArray(previous[0], languages) > -1 ? 0: 1] = previous[0];
        }

        selections[isLetter ? 1 : 0] = $(this).val();
        $("#camouflage").val(selections.length > 1 ? selections.join(',') : selections[0]);
    });
});
```